# FCM, how to allow messages from API's and avoid from Console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM message can be pushed from console and using api

from console (https://console.firebase.google.com)

using api (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send)

In both case when app is in **foreground**, message is received in service that extends FirebaseMessagingService, in onMessageReceived we can filter requests by custom param in bundle, but when app is in  **background** and message is sent from console, receiver is not called, and the push message is somehow added.

Is possible to handle this request?

Comment: when message sent with "data payload"       onMessageRecived is called whether the app in forground or in background so you can send notification with datapayload and do your checks that can be a solution

Comment: @abdullahyousry what about without datapayload?

Comment: when app in background it goes to system tray 
they are explained here 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Send a `data`-only message payload.

Answer (score 0):

When app is in background and you suppose to fire notification via console at that time notification will come in notification tray rather than going to your service.

That will mentioned in guidelines.

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

So if you want to still handle notifications then, you have to set proper payload for same. So that whenever user click on notification then it will react accordingly.

For disabling notification try following,

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
```

Comment: I want to avoid display of notification

Comment: okie you want to avoid notification only from via console right ? not via API?

Comment: yep, avoid Console, receive API

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging support two [types of messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):

> - Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." [When the app is not active], these are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
> - Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

The Firebase console always sends notification messages, which are (when the app is not active) handled by the system. There is no way to intercept these messages in that case.

If you want to always receive the message in your application code, you should use a data message, which can only be sent using the API.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to handle messages when app is in foreground/background. In both cases you can handle it by implementing `onMessageReceived`. The only difference is, You have to put `data` in your JSON Message. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/4935997) you can find more.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { 
   Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
   String myKey = data.get("myKey");
}
```

Comment: When you send a message with console of fire base and app is in background, at that time onMessageReceived will not be called as per fire base guidelines.

Comment: @MohitTrivedi Here are documents about Receiving Notification and Sending  Message From Console. None of them mentioned about Not receiving console messages in background by implementing onMessageReceived . https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive , https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-with-console

Comment: Messages with both notification and data payload, when received in the background. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.